# Cloudant docker image is too old and does not work with "partition" option

Tags: docker, cloudant

I'm using Loopback 4 and trying to run migrate option. When using local docker image of Cloudant (ibmcom/cloudant-developer), it throws following error:

'Invalid key partitioned for this request.'

However, it works fine with Cloudant instance on IBM public cloud.

Here's the full error message:

```
name: 'Error',
error: 'invalid_key',
reason: 'Invalid key partitioned for this request.',
scope: 'couch',
statusCode: 400,
request: {
method: 'post',
headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json', accept: 'application/json' },
uri: 'http://XXXXXX:XXXXXX@localhost:8888/auth-clients/_index',
body: '{"index":{"fields":[{"loopback__model__name":"asc"}]},"partitioned":false,"ddoc":"LBModel__auth_clients__LBIndex__loopback__model__name_index","name":"loopback__model__name_index","type":"json"}',
qsStringifyOptions: { arrayFormat: 'repeat' }
},
headers: {
uri: 'http://XXXXXX:XXXXXX@localhost:8888/auth-clients/_index',
statusCode: 400,
'cache-control': 'must-revalidate',
'content-type': 'application/json',
date: 'Wed, 05 Feb 2020 11:34:54 GMT',
'x-couch-request-id': '169749e8da',
'x-couchdb-body-time': '0'
},
errid: 'non_200',
description: 'couch returned 400'
```

Answer (score 1):

The ibmcom/cloudant-developer image is based on Cloudant Local, which is EOL, and so will never be updated. If you can live without Cloudant-specific features, you might want to try a recent [CouchDB image](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb), which does include support for partitioned databases.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I've tried with latest docker image of CouchDB as well, but am getting the same error message.  CouchDB supports "partitioned" database, but am not sure if the docker image supports it or not.  Either there is some issue with latest loopback connector for cloudant or with docker images of Cloudant and CouchDB.  I'm not sure who's going to fix this.

Comment: Partitioned databases are only supported in the next major version of CouchDB. That is currently in RC stage right now.